# Workflows and publishing feature with e-mail notification sends mutliple e-mails 

Tags: 2010, workflow, publishing

I have a requirement which states "When a document is being uploaded to the document library, an email should be sent for approval". I'm using a SharePoint Designer workflow for this. I also need to have the publishing feature on the document library.

Presently what is happening, when I add a document to document library, the workflow is triggered and the e-mail is sent and workflow is getting approved. But later when I try to publish, again the workflow is getting started. How can I prevent this? Or am I using the wrong approach?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by publish? This word can have several meanings for SharePoint people and I would like to be certin we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: i mean i have activated publishing feature for that document library.after worklfow is approved i am tring to publish the page.so again the workflow is getting triggered

Comment: You may have the workflow set to if anything changes about any of the pages and it may not be just an approval workflow.